# Pass and parse arguments from a <div>'s data-options attribute to a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html, attributes, custom-data-attribute

I have a `<div>` with some options in a `data-options` attribute:

```
<div class="slider" data-options="container: value, speed: 1000, edgePadding: 45, lazyload: true">
```

This attribute contains the arguments I need for every `<div>` with a `.slider` class.

I'm saving those arguments into an `options` variable with:

```
var options = value.dataset.options;
```

Then I need to pass those options to a function `tns` for each `.slider` element:

```
var forEach = function (array, callback, scope) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    callback.call(scope, i, array[i]);
  }
};

var sliders = document.querySelectorAll('.slider');

forEach(sliders, function (index, value) {
  var options = value.dataset.options;

  let slider = tns({
      /************ PARAMETERS GO HERE ***********/
  });
});
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) if you change a bit the syntax of the value of that attribute adding curly braces and escaped quotes (`&quot;`):

```js
const slider = document.getElementById('slider');

console.log(JSON.parse(`${ slider.dataset.options }`));
```

```html
<div id="slider" data-options="{ &quot;container&quot;: &quot;value&quot;, &quot;speed&quot;: 1000, &quot;edgePadding&quot;: 45, &quot;lazyload&quot;: true }">
```

Another alternative that looks better would be to use single quotes `'` and [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval):

```js
const slider = document.getElementById('slider');

console.log(eval(`(${ slider.dataset.options })`));
```

```html
<div id="slider" data-options="{ 'container': 'value', 'speed': 1000, 'edgePadding': 45, 'lazyload': true }">
```

Or just parse the value of the attribute yourself:

```js
const slider = document.getElementById('slider');
const options = {};

slider.dataset.options.split(',').forEach((pair) => {
  const [key, value] = pair.split(':');
  
  options[key.trim()] = value.trim();
});

console.log(options);
```

```html
<div id="slider" data-options="container: value, speed: 1000, edgePadding: 45, lazyload: true">
```

More elaborated parsing logic:

```js
const slider = document.getElementById('slider');
const options = {};

slider.dataset.options.split(',').forEach((pair) => {
  const [key, value] = pair.split(':');
  
  let parsedValue = value.trim();
  
  if (!isNaN(parsedValue)) {
    options[key.trim()] = +parsedValue;
  } else if (parsedValue === 'true' || parsedValue === 'false') {
    options[key.trim()] = parsedValue === 'true';
  } else {
    options[key.trim()] = parsedValue;
  }
});

console.log(options);
```

```html
<div id="slider" data-options="container: value, speed: 1000, edgePadding: 45, lazyload: true">
```

Comment: @ysanmiguel I have updated the answer with 2 different examples. One using `JSON.parse()`, if you can change a bit the syntax of the value you set on that `data-` attribute, and another one parsing it yourself if you can't change that syntax.

Comment: Mate great, thanks a lot. I solve the problem using the JSON.parse and JSON syntax inside data-options. Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1):

Please consider pass the data options separately.

For this:

```
 <div class="slider" data-options="container: value, speed: 1000, edgePadding: 45, lazyload: true">
```

is better

```
 <div class="slider" data-container="value" data-speed="1000" data-edgePadding"45" data-lazyload"true">
```

And then catch each data-element:

*In plain JS...*

```
 document.querySelector(".slider").getAttribute("data-container");
 document.querySelector(".slider").getAttribute("data-speed");
 //...
```

*In jQuery...*

```
 $('.slider').data('container')
 $('.slider').data('speed')
 $('.slider').data('container')
 //...
```